# Problem with loading spacy.load('en_core_web_md')

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, anaconda, spacy

**I have installed in anaconda the packages shown below:**

- spacy                      2.2.2
- spacy-model-en_core_web_md 2.2.5
- spacy-model-en_core_web_sm 2.2.5
- python                     3.6.2

**The above packages were installed in conda with the commands shown below:**

- conda install -c conda-forge spacy=2.2.2
- conda install -c conda-forge spacy-model-en_core_web_sm
- conda install -c conda-forge spacy-model-en_core_web_md

**When i load en_core_web_md and en_core_web_sm, i get an error message shown below:**

- import spacy
- import en_core_web_sm
- nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

```
Error message:
-> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-d6345e302427> in <module>
      1 import spacy
      2 import en_core_web_sm
----> 3 nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
      4 
      5 #import en_core_web_sm

~\anaconda3\envs\ADS99\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py in load(name, **overrides)
     17 from . import util
     18 from .util import register_architecture, get_architecture
---> 19 from .language import component
     20 
     21 

~\anaconda3\envs\ADS99\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py in load_model(name, **overrides)
    117 
    118     path (unicode or Path): Path to new data directory.
--> 119     """
    120     global _data_path
    121     _data_path = ensure_path(path)

OSError: Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'
```

**I tried a different way of loading en_core_web_sm but again i got a different error:**

- import spacy
- import en_core_web_sm
- nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

```
Error message:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-9427d7caa44a> in <module>
      1 import spacy
      2 import en_core_web_sm
----> 3 nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
      4 
      5 

~\anaconda3\envs\ADS99\lib\site-packages\en_core_web_sm\__init__.py in load(**overrides)
     10 
     11 def load(**overrides):
---> 12     return load_model_from_init_py(__file__, **overrides)

~\anaconda3\envs\ADS99\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py in load_model_from_init_py(init_file, **overrides)
    174         return Path(path)
    175     else:
--> 176         return path
    177 
    178 

~\anaconda3\envs\ADS99\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py in load_model_from_path(model_path, meta, **overrides)
    143 
    144 
--> 145 def make_layer(arch_config):
    146     arch_func = get_architecture(arch_config["arch"])
    147     return arch_func(arch_config["config"])

~\anaconda3\envs\ADS99\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py in get_lang_class(lang)
     47 
     48     factories = "spacy_factories"
---> 49     languages = "spacy_languages"
     50     displacy_colors = "spacy_displacy_colors"
     51     lookups = "spacy_lookups"

~\anaconda3\envs\ADS99\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    124                 break
    125             level += 1
--> 126     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    127 
    128 

~\anaconda3\envs\ADS99\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

~\anaconda3\envs\ADS99\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

~\anaconda3\envs\ADS99\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

~\anaconda3\envs\ADS99\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _load_unlocked(spec)

~\anaconda3\envs\ADS99\lib\importlib\_bootstrap_external.py in exec_module(self, module)

~\anaconda3\envs\ADS99\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

~\anaconda3\envs\ADS99\lib\site-packages\spacy\lang\en\__init__.py in <module>
     12 from ..tokenizer_exceptions import BASE_EXCEPTIONS
     13 from ..norm_exceptions import BASE_NORMS
---> 14 from ...language import Language
     15 from ...attrs import LANG, NORM
     16 from ...util import update_exc, add_lookups

~\anaconda3\envs\ADS99\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py in <module>
     18 from .vocab import Vocab
     19 from .lemmatizer import Lemmatizer
---> 20 from .lookups import Lookups
     21 from .analysis import analyze_pipes, analyze_all_pipes, validate_attrs
     22 from .compat import izip, basestring_, is_python2, class_types

~\anaconda3\envs\ADS99\lib\site-packages\spacy\lookups.py in <module>
      4 import srsly
      5 from collections import OrderedDict
----> 6 from preshed.bloom import BloomFilter
      7 
      8 from .errors import Errors

bloom.pyx in init preshed.bloom()

AttributeError: type object 'preshed.bloom.BloomFilter' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

If someone can provide me any hint on how this could issue could be fixed, i would be really grateful.

Answer (score 3):

you can try using anaconda prompt, and you can do this:

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
python -m spacy download en
```

after that, you can load the model via its full package name.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

and you can try to test it, like this:

```
check = nlp("How's your spicy its really spicy, don't you think?")
```

and do this

```
for token in check:
print (token)
```

if its really work, it turn out be like this.

```
How
's
your
spicy
its
really
spicy
,
do
n't
you
think
?
```

good luck.

Answer (score 1):

find a location of your 'en_core_web_sm' in spacy use in load directory.
e.g
model = spacy.load('path/....')

Answer (score 0):

Is the version of Python you're using to install the `en_core_web_sm` model the same as the version of Python you're using to consume the model? If not, it could be that the SpaCy model cannot be found by your application because it is installed under a different Python version.

You can easily confirm this by running the following tests:

From console:

```sh
python --version
```

From your code:

```py
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have successfully downloaded the model check where the model is installed. I have found that downloading en_core_web_md in a conda environment can lead it to be saved in the site-packages folder directly (using windows) NOT the **data** folder in the spacy package where the load_model looks by default.